# How can I convince Firefox to redraw CSS Pseudo-elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm having issues getting Firefox to update a webpage when its class is changed dynamically.

I'm using an HTML `table` element. When the user clicks a cell in the table header, my script toggles the class back and forth between `sorted_asc` and `sorted_des`. I have pseudo element which adds an arrow glyph (pointing up or down) depending on which class the cell currently is.

```
.thead .tr .sorted_asc .cell:after {
    content: ' \25B2';
}
```

The problem is, that when you click the cell header a second time, the page doesn't update the arrow... until the user mouses away from the element. I think it's a bug as it works fine in Safari, and as I don't see any `:hover` tags in my CSS or other entries that might interfere.

Anyone seen this before, or know how to work around the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kind of cheesy, but since you're using javascript anyway, try this after you changed the className:

```
document.body.style.display = 'none';
document.body.style.display = 'block';
```

This will re-render the layout and often solves these kind of bugs. Not always, though.

Comment: well, it's a couple years later, but if you're still around i want to re-thank you :) this really helped me out

Comment: Thanks, that's so nice! Glad to have been of help :)

Comment: I'd like to add that in some cases (not sure when), that this doesn't seem to work, but changing the opacity via `document.body.style.opacity = '0.99999'; document.body.style.opacity = '1';` seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: I have an issue where the animation was not working in firefox. I was using jquery toggle class to add a class to an element which changed its position. I was using transition all. In firefox it did not work. But once I added this fix it started to work.

Comment: That's nice to hear! Nice to know that this answer still helps people, after all these years.

Answer (score 4):

This is 2014 and none of the proposed solutions on this page seem to work. I found another way : detach the element from the DOM and append it back where it was.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use different CSS to accomplish the same thing without relying on the :after pseudo-selector? You might be able to simple define a background-image which you align as needed (I assume you would want the arrow on the right hand side).

For example:

```
.thead .tr .sorted_asc .sorted_asc {
  background: url(images/down_arrow.png) no-repeat right;
}

.thead .tr .sorted_asc .sorted_des {
  background: url(images/up_arrow.png) no-repeat right;
}
```

I only suggest this since I assume there isn't a specific reason why you need to use the :after pseudo-class. If you do need to use it, please update.

Answer (score 0):

The bug can still be triggered in Firefox 58. Thankfully the opacity trick also still works. Just make sure to time it correctly. You might need to set a timeout between opacity changes.